# Applescript: How to copy paragraphs 3 to 10 of a text holding object into anther object?

Tags: parsing, applescript

I have object `theContents` which contains an email's contents (body text). These emails are auto generated from a website and are structured in a consistent form.

I wish to omit the first three lines and copy all the remaining text into another object so I can then paste it into a spreadsheet.

Having trouble with the grammar.

Comment: Question... does paragraph three always end with a particular string, or does paragraph 4 always begin with a specific string? If so, you can use offset.

Comment: Yes all the auto generated emails have line 3 start with "email: " followed by the email address of the subscriber. Occasionally non-auto generated emails arrive in the same inbox but they are exceptions and can be filtered out prior to this step.

Comment: So another option is to set o to offset of "email:" and then get text o thru -1 of theString

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try code below.

The key to which is the `thru` keyword which defines the end of the range you want, and using negative numbers lets you work backwards from the end. With -1 being the last item, and -2 the second last, etc.

```
set theContents to "Here is line one.
And here is line two.
Here is line three.
Now four,
Then five..
How do you do?"

set theFilteredContents to text (paragraphs 4) thru -1 of theContents
```

Comment: Don't do that. Use `text (paragraph 4) thru -1 of theContents`. That specifies a continuous text range starting at paragraph 4 and ending at the end of the text.

Comment: adamh, don't mess with delimiters without doing it properly, saving and restoring. And foo, paragraph 4 does not return the text position. Your line does not compile.

Comment: @jweaks the old reset delimiters argument. I prefer code brevity and readability, especially as if i ever do use 'text item' access i always set the delimiter first. Keep an eye on your scripts, you may find you always set the delimiters first? Though there is valid point for bigger complex scripts and calling sub functions that reset delimiters - ouch. To me it seems a choice between simplicity or cautious scripting, and i'd decide depending on the target/use-age of the script.

Comment: @jweaks: "paragraph 4 does not return the text position". I don't think you fully understand how AppleScript's range reference forms work. That's a valid 'reference' (a query, really), and AppleScript knows how to resolve it for native strings. Replace the last 2 lines of adamh's example with it, and it will work. If you can't compile it, you probably typed it wrong. Or perhaps you're trying to use it on a scriptable application object, not an AS string, in which case the application will return an error if it doesn't support or can't resolve that particular reference.

Comment: foo, indeed, I should never try and help in a rush from my phone screen, where I misread. Apologies. adamh, I'd really suggest encouraging folks to be intentional at atid use, AND, to use Applescript's, in case they are using in another block.

Comment: Hey @foo, i'm seeing no difference in the result from your line or my line. Is it just a code style difference in how we cast back to text? I am using the parenthesis to wrap that logical block of code to cast.

Comment: The reference specifies a continuous text range. There's no text->list or list->text conversions involved. It's just best practice: simpler, faster, and doesn't alter the original (CR/LF/CRLF) paragraph separators.

Comment: @foo, great i got it. nice tip, have updated answer.

Comment: @foo Why are the parenthesis around (paragraphs 4)? Surely 'paragraphs' is plural and therefore the arguments are 4 thru -1, but any other arrangement of parens gives me an error. I don't get it. Also whats the significance of using the 'text' ?modifier as opposed to jweaks alternative script above that leaves it out?

Comment: The parentheses are necessary cause the paragraph query is just for the 4, not for the -1. The -1 is a text position, namely the last one in the string.   Using text… thru is good because it is avoiding a coercion to a list and back to string.

Answer (score 1):

```
set theString to "Line one.
Line two.
Line three.
Line four.
Line five.
Line six.
Line seven."

set theResult to paragraphs 4 thru -1 of theString
set otid to AppleScript's text item delimiters
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to return
set theResult to theResult as string
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to otid
return theResult
```